# How do I say "Is this person serious?"

Tags: grammar

Is "この人は本気ですか？" correct?

Any better ways to say this?

Comment: I think 真面目　（まじめ)　is better for this usage of serious. Or maybe 「マジで？」for short. It's short for "Are they serious?" in context.

Comment: Can you provide some context? In what situation do you want to use the phrase? You might say この人、本気で言ってる？ or この人、マジで言ってる？ etc. depending on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this person **serious**?

According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, there are two possible meanings for "serious" as:

(1) not joking or pretending if someone is serious about something they say or plan to do, they really mean it and are not joking or pretending

(2) quiet/sensible someone who is serious is very quiet and sensible, and does not laugh and joke much

For (1), the given sentence will be intepreted as "この人は真剣｛しんけん｝/本気｛ほんき｝ですか？" or "この人、真剣｛しんけん｝/本気｛ほんき｝ですか？", and for (2) it will be as "この人は真面目{まじめ}/生真面目｛きまじめ｝ですか？" or "この人、真面目{まじめ}/生真面目｛きまじめ｝ですか？".